# NEST ElasticSearch Delete type

Tags: .net, nest

I will be very grateful if someone tells me the correct way to delete all data in specific type using NEST.
I have one index in my elasticsearch and two types and I would like to be able to delete all data in one or the other type when I need it.

My current idea is

```
ElasticClient.DeleteByQuery<ISearchData>(q => q.Index(indexName).Type(type.ToString()).Query(qu => qu.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.MatchAll()))));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch and NEST: How do you purge all documents from an index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917221/elasticsearch-and-nest-how-do-you-purge-all-documents-from-an-index)

Comment: @Jim G. it's easy to delete all documents from the index. My question was about the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var deleteByQuery = client.DeleteByQuery<Document>(d => d.MatchAll());
```

UPDATE:

In case you are using one class to store documents in two types, you can use `.Type()` parameter to specify which one would you like to delete.

```
client.DeleteByQuery<Document>(descriptor => descriptor.Type("type1").Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
```

My example:

```
client.Index(new Document {Id = 2}, descriptor => descriptor.Type("type1"));
client.Index(new Document {Id = 1}, descriptor => descriptor.Type("type1"));
client.Index(new Document {Id = 2}, descriptor => descriptor.Type("type2"));

client.Refresh();

client.DeleteByQuery<Document>(descriptor => descriptor.Type("type1").Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have documents of the same C# type in two different Elastic Search types, so if I follow your suggestion, I will delete both of my types when I need to delete only one.